# loop every 3 lines, Input is from txt file then must Output Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I need to transfer the 1st line from a txt file to Column A then the 2nd line to Column B then 3rd line to Column C in the same row and then do it again for the next lines every 3 lines. every 3 lines is like 3 columns in 1 row.

My txt file looks like this:

```
7:52:01 AM sherr
hello GOOD morning .
おはようございます。
7:52:09 AM sherr
Who ?
誰?
7:52:16 AM sherr
OK .
わかりました。
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYaoo.png)
I tried this code btw,

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

file1 = open('chat_20220207131707.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
Lines = file1.readlines()

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws= wb.worksheets[0]

x = 1
y = 1

if y < 4:
    for row in Lines:
        cell = ws.cell(row=x, column=y)
        cell.value = row[0]
    y += 1
else:
    x += 1
    y = 1

df.to_excel('sherrplease.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only tried converting the txt file to excel file. I still don't know how to properly code in python as I am still a beginner :'(

Comment: does the source file contain the empty lines that are present in the sample provided above?

Comment: also, never post code/text as a screenshot, you cannot copy/paste a screenshot. See the formatting [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: hello uhhmm I edited my post and the text file looks like the one in the picture. It doesn't have the empty lines, I just clicked on enter every new line because it won't show the same way from my source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started (without using *pandas*):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

with open('chat_20220207131707.txt', encoding='utf-8') as sherr:
    row = 0
    ws = wb.active
    for column, line in enumerate(sherr.readlines()):
        if (c := column % 3 + 1) == 1:
            row += 1
        ws.cell(row=row, column=c, value=line.strip())
    wb.save('sherrplease.xlsx')
```